# Creating triggers in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger on my mysql database table. I am writing the following code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON billingrates FOR EACH ROW;
```

But when I run this, I am getting the following error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 2

Please guide me. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: See [13.1.20 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate what is trigger body and trigger order? Also is it mandatory? I read the document but I am not able to understand it completely.I am new to this. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You haven't specify the body of trigger. What do you want to do

Comment: Actually I want cancel automatic deletion of rows. And when I inquired about this, I got a solution to write a trigger.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do. Can you please specify what your trigger should do and the table which should fire it.- I assume that the automatic cancellation of rows has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `barcode_master` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE library_emp_master SET job_type = 1 WHERE barcode_no =   OLD.barcode_no; 
END;
```

Comment: Gives me  this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 @Jalpa

Comment: @rushikulkarni Please provide another table where you want to trigger. Please check my answer.

Comment: @rushikulkarni i have added trigger to change library_emp_master when delete the barcode_master table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming body for trigger. Let's you want to take a backup before delete

`DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON billingrates FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(old.column1);
End $$`